# Is there a rules based IMAP email processing engine?

Tags: python, email, imap, rule-engine

In the past, I have written a script using the Python IMAP library to move certain emails in my Gmail Inbox that matched a certain pattern into the SPAM folder.

I would like to set up more rules like, "archive mails from newsletter.com after two weeks".

Since this seems to be a common use case, I was wondering whether anyone had written a more generic tool to implement rules based email processing. I'm not looking for natural English rules but something a bit easier to configure than writing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used http://fdm.sourceforge.net/ to do this with local mboxes. Section 6.4 of the page I linked says that you can also have an action be on a remote IMAP(S) server.

Mutt also supports connecting directly to an IMAP server and has powerful regex-based tagging and actions based on tags.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out. However, the FAQ says: "12.3 Keep doesn't work with gmail! - This is because gmail is broken, see:
http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/faq.html#faq-notabug-gmail-bug"

Comment: That seems to be a POP3 problem. I was able to use IMAP fine with my Gmail account, though that was over a year ago.